# ¿Como pasar DataGridView a Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports

Tengo un `GridView` en asp.net y necesito que al dar click a un botón imprimir me genere un reporte crystal reports con los datos del `GridView`.

Asi he llenado mi `GridView`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from table where cod_user='"+ Session["Cod_user"]+"'", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
gridview1.Visible = true;
gridview1.DataSource = dt;
gridview1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Utilizo **webform.aspx** con c#

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="RecepF" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
<div class="card-header""><i class="fa fa-table" font-weight: bold;>TABLA</i><button type="button" id="BTN" OnClick="BTN_Click"><span class="fa fa-print"></span>IMPRIMIR</button>  

  <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CssClass="table table-bordered table-sm"
  ShowFooter="True">
<emptydatatemplate>
        ¡No se encontraron reportes!  
    </emptydatatemplate>                

    <Columns>
         <%--campos...--%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="campo1" HeaderText="campo1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="campo1" />
     -----muchos campos mas------
         </Columns>
  </asp:GridView> 
    </div>
  </div>

//Evento click del boton
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int16));
        dt.Columns.Add("NombreUsuario", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Apellido", typeof(string));
        foreach (**DataGridViewRow** dgr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells[0].Value, dgr.Cells[1].Value, dgr.Cells[2].Value, dgr.Cells[3].Value);
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.WriteXmlSchema("Ejemplo.xml");
        CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1();
        cr.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

Me muestra un error que dice"El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombre DataGridViewRow no se encontro ¿falta una directiva using?"
Gracias
Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer de esta forma, solo debes de modificar la linea donde se inicializa el reporte, suponiendo que tu reporte se llamara así: `ReporteCrystal`

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = 
new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from table where cod_user='"+ Session["Cod_user"]+"'", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

RegisCrystalReport cos = new RegisCrystalReport();
cos.SetDataSource(dt);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cos;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

En el **aspx** para crear un boton que puedas llamar un metodo sería de esta forma:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="IMPRIMIR" OnClick="ImprimirReporte_Click"/>
```

Este es un ejemplo para llenarlo con un dataSet  que es otra forma de llenar el reporte sin hacer la consulta de nuevo, solo que tienes que agregar las columnas de el reporte

> Nota: `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int16));
        dt.Columns.Add("NombreUsuario", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Apellido", typeof(string));
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells[0].Value, dgr.Cells[1].Value, dgr.Cells[2].Value, dgr.Cells[3].Value);
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.WriteXmlSchema("Ejemplo.xml");
        CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1();
        cr.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: gracias por responder, asi seria para el evento onclick?

Comment: @sunflowe Seria mejor si editas la pregunta y muestras el codigo aspx asi te puede ayudar en esa parte también

Comment: hola ya esta editado

Comment: hola gracias por el aporte, pero hay alguna manera de hacerlo si tener que hacer de nuevo la consulta select en el boton_click?. El codigo que mostre de principio es solo para llenar mi datagrid, ahora solo quiero pasar el grid a crystal report sin hacer el query sql

Comment: Solo tienes que llenar el dataSet para hacerlo pero explicartelo, seria incorrecto porque tendrias que hacer otra pregunta para hacerlo

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: una cosa mas me marca este error: EL NOMBRE DE ESPACIOS DataGridViewRow NO SE ENCONTRO

Comment: gridview1 cambialo por esto asi se llama el que tienes creado

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in nombredemigrd.Rows) pero en esto me marca el error: 'DataGridViewRow'

Comment: @sunflower **edita la pregunta** y agrega la descripción de los errores. ¿Sabes usar `try/catch`?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Gracias por responder podrias decirme como porfavor

Comment: @sunflower [Cómo usar el try/catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions). En vez de `Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);` coloca un `Label` en tu webform y usa: `Label1.Text = ex.ToString();`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave hola el proeblema es que marca el error en la palabra DataGridViewRow. Error: EL NOMBRE DE ESPACIOS DataGridViewRow NO SE ENCONTRO

Comment: @sunflower, estás usando un `GridView` ¿porqué colocas que es una `DataGridView`? son dos controles diferentes. En lugar de `DataGridViewRow` usa `GridViewRow`

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave gracias no sabia eso ya se soluciono ese problema, ahora me muestra el siguiente error:'El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
Nombre del parámetro: index'
en la linea:dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells[0].Value, dgr.Cells[1].Value, dgr.Cells[2].Value.............

Comment: @sunflower deberías investigar un poco mas, no puedo resolverte todas tus inquietudes. Ya la respuesta de Raul es correcta, tienes el DataTable y se lo pasas al Crystal Report.

Comment: Buen día, estoy aplicando el mismo concepto, pero el problema es que cada vez que llamo al formulario me sigue acumulado los valores del llamado anterior, que debería usar.

Comment: @Franklin Cabrera has pobado limpiar la variable cuando termina de llenar el reporte

Answer (score 0):

USANDO CICLO FOR

```
   public void Fatura()
    {

        DatosFactura df = new DatosFactura();//este es el dataset

        int filas = Gridp.Rows.Count; //esto te cuenta las filas del datagrid

        
        for(int i=0;i<=filas-2;i++)//recorremos fila por fila el datagrid
        {

            df.Tables[0].Rows.Add
                ( 
                new object[] 
                {
                   Gridp[0,i].Value,
                   Gridp[1,i].Value,
                   Gridp[2,i].Value
                }                
                );
        }

        reporte fc = new reporte();
        fc.SetDataSource(df);  
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource= fc;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

USANDO FOREACH

```
  public void Fatura()
    {

        DatosFactura df = new DatosFactura();//Este es el dataset

        foreach(DataGridViewRow dgr in Gridp.Rows)
       
        {

            df.Tables[0].Rows.Add
                (
                   dgr.Cells[0].Value, dgr.Cells[1].Value, dgr.Cells[2].Value
                              
                );
        }

        reporte fc = new reporte();
        fc.SetDataSource(df);  
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource= fc;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```